# Удаление записей из таблицы в форме через VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Что здесь не так??

```
Function delete1(posh As String)

Dim db As Database
Dim r As Recordset
Dim i As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set r = db.OpenRecordset("select * from obekt")
i = 1
Do Until r.EOF
If r!adresa = posh Then
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * from obekt where id=i"
End If
i = i + 1
r.MoveNext
Loop

End Function
```

именно вот тут

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * from obekt where id=i"
```

Comment: А с какого перепугу считается, что записи в рекордсете будут возвращаться в порядке сортировки по ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код эквивалентен команде

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * from obekt where adresa='" & posh & "'"
```

если adresa - текстовое поле. Надежнее при этом замаскировать возможные апострофы внутри текста:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * from obekt where adresa='" & Replace(posh, "'", "''") & "'"
```

В исходном же варианте в проблемном выражении i не должно быть внутри SQL выражения:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Delete * from obekt where id=" & i
```

Но и после этого исправления код не гарантирует надежную работу, т.к. записи могут идти в непредсказуемом порядке и с пропусками в нумерации.